# Create line graph with ggplot2, using time periods as x-variable

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2, line

I am very new to R, and so this question is extremely elementary, but I can't solve it myself. I would very much appreciate your help.

This is a sort of dataframe I want to use:

```
     Period                           Value   Cut.off
1   January 1998 - August 2002      8.798129    1.64
2   September 2002 - Jun 2006       4.267268    1.64
3   Jul 2006 - Dec 2009             7.280275    1.64
```

This the code I am using:

```
require(ggplot2)
bq <- ggplot(data=glomor, aes(x=as.character(Period),y=Value))+geom_point()+ylim(0,10)

bq <- bq + scale_x_discrete(limits=c("January 1998 - August 2002","September 2002 - Jun 2006","Jul 2006 - Dec 2009"))

bq + geom_line()
```

I receive the following error message:

```
geom_path: Each group consist of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
```

How do I need to change the code, so that the points will be connected by a line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should add `group=1` in your `aes()` call to conect points with line. This will *inform* `geom_line()` that all your points belong to one level and they should be connected.

```
ggplot(data=glomor, aes(x=as.character(Period),y=Value,group=1))+
   geom_point()+ylim(0,10) + geom_line()
```